Что такое события с точки зрения реализации?
Вопрос возможно глупый, но мне не до конца понятно как работают обработчики какого-либо события под капотом. Например функция, которая вызывается при изменении какого-нибудь файла или браузерные события в JavaScript. Для всего этого есть свои уже готовые инструменты, которые можно использовать, но как реализуются такие инструменты, например то же событие во время изменения файла. Способ из while (true), который первый приходит в голову является плохим, насколько я знаю, да и в принципе туда прийдется добавлять минимальную задержку, чтобы не перегружать процессор, но как-то же смогли реализовать события, которые не нагружают процессор и срабатывают мгновенно. Можете объяснить как это реализуется на низком уровне или поделиться соответствующими источниками?

Операционная система прекрасно знает, когда она изменяет файл, и соответственно может вызвать обработчики сразу после этого изменения

Да вроде всё как в жизни. Зашёл ты значит в мак, заказал бургер и указал, что будешь сидеть за столиком номер 5. Тебя записали в список получения бургеров. Пришёл другой чел и заказал колу и указал, что будет сидеть за столиком 9. Его тоже записали в список, но уже на получение колы....... Сидите, ждёте.... Вот на кухне приготовили бургер, смотрят в списках - ага, вот за столиком №5 заказывали...несут туда..... Налили колу - смотрят в списках - ага, надо отнести на столи №9....несут туда......... вот и всё

Посмотри паттерн Наблюдатель (Observer). Собсн это всё, как будут работать события и уведомления о них.

Примерно как вы написали про while(true) - так и есть. И про то что цикл вываливается [спит какое то время] - тоже такое есть. Цикл когда вываливается [спит] - это значит в некотором смысле - отдаёт себя диспетчеру например операционной системы. Или любой иной системы, если в этой системе своя реализация диспетчера. А диспетчер "будит" цикл когда нужно [по истечении времени сна], и цикл опять вертится. Как ни странно - это всё стоит не дорого, и при вменяемой реализации диспетчера - оверхед на диспетчеризацию весьма незначителен.

И само собой в цикле проверяется какой то condition [условие], и если условие срабатывает - то вызывается эта самая "функция события". Это всё обычно объясняется в общей теме многопоточности.

Концепция выглядит так:

есть диспетчер событий
вы пишите функцию-обработчик события и регистрирует ее в диспетчере событий
диспетчер будет вызывать эту функцию, при наступлении события

